Anti-Mythical Creature Armory: Fear Toxin
Framing: we are trying to arm an order of knights with weapons and equipment in the modern age (21st century) to combat and police mages, vampires, fae, werewolves, and other monsters of myth. A weapon I’d like for this order to have is a ‘censer’ of sorts that emanates a small cloud but a further reaching aroma/odor that would cause someone who is within its range of effect/breathing it in to feel fear, anxiety, and depression as well as make breathing and speaking difficult. This weapon would be a non-immediately lethal option to reduce the effectiveness of mages in this setting by targeting the source of their magic: verbal casting (spells must be spoken aloud) and 'willpower'(described as having the 'will' to continue a fight and the presence of mind to keep 'casting')
The Question: What real life chemicals or compound or what have you would this mix being burnt need to be made of in order to have this effect? What would it's range likely be? Would it have a noticeable smell?
Additional notes:
I'd like the range to be several feet around whomever is carrying the censer (able to fill a medium sized room and/or still have an effect while outdoors on any mages within a relative area.)
The 'dose' necesary to take effect should be incredibly fast acting and take minimal exposure to take effect.
preferably the aromatic effect should reach further than the visible cloud and noticeable smell.
The effects that would also influence the wielder can be ignored for sake of setting so don't worry about them.
Effecting bystanders is also not an issue so if there's obvious collateral damage that we'd see from the use of this weapon that is fine.

We have a strict one question per post policy on this site. Supplemental questions are still questions. Please then and other extraneous information.

I have difficulty with the overarching question. Not only are they several, but it does not prevent answers like 'napalm' or 'mustard gas'. People who know those substances, which they might encounter in such a war where chemical agents are used, will definitely have a healthy response of fear. War is chaotic and unpredictable. If you are being gassed or bombed by napalm you bet there's few who do not panic. Releasing smells they might encounter in such situations can make for very intense emotions.

There are quite a few constraints on this: fear, difficulty breathing, cloud, smell, fast acting, range of aromatic effect... a plausible answer is probably going to take the path of a cop-out and say something like "they're using focused monochromatic terahertz to heat the guy's amygdalae and Broca's area and all this other stuff is a ... smoke screen!"  I'm not sure if that's OK.

There's a fairly broad body of knowledge on what substances typically have what effect on humans.  There is no such body of knowledge on what substances would affect "mages, vampires, fae, werewolves, and other monsters of myth", some of which (eg vampires) don't even breathe in some mythology.  Finally, for any creature that does need to breathe, there will be a very narrow window between "non-lethal" and "lethal" that will vary from person to person.

Why would you want it to be a real-life chemical? Your world is well into the realm of fantasy, so employ fantastical elements. Just make it a pepper spray-like weapon that uses something made up.
